# Changing Apache's ServerTokens with no effect

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

In Ubuntu 9.10 I can't get apache directive `ServerTokens` to work. My httpd.conf looks like below.

```
ServerName server.mydomain.com
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod
```

ServerName solved startup warnings, but ServerTokens doesn't take. Both Firebug and nmap reports `Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:
ServerTokens ProductOnly

Probably goes without..but you will need to reload for changes to take effect.

Comment: Same server signature after apache restart :(

Comment: Perhaps the ServerTokens directive is listed in one of the include files. "grep -Ri servertokens /etc/httpd/"

Comment: Of course, genius! The server token was set in `/etc/apache2/conf.d/security`. Thank you!

Comment: haha, I spent 3 hours one time trying to figure out why my ssl config for a vhost wasn't working. Include files are sneaky! ;)

Comment: is this `security` directory or file exists in wampserver apache? @Znarkus

Comment: On Ubuntu with Apache 2.4, it is defined in `/etc/apache2/conf-available/security.conf`

Comment: Changing the value in `conf-available/security.conf` didn't work for me. I added the line to the very bottom of `apache2.conf` and that made it work.